# The values stored in the table of ms access are not storing in proper order

Tags: java, sql, database, ms-access-2007

I have made a project which is based on the Employee management system on the clicking on save button the values of fields Date of joining(doj) and personal name(p_name) are not storing in proper order, the value are showing like->
(doj) showing information of (p_name) and (p_name) showing the information of (doj).

```
     //   Save Personal Information of Employee Master



                  if(ae.getSource()==pi_save)
                 {
                    try
                    {
                            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");

                            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection
                            ("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver 
                             (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\\Program
                             Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0\\bin\\payroll.mdb;","","");

                            PreparedStatement psm=con.prepareStatement

                            ("insert into pinfo(eid,p_name,fname,doj,dob,desg,pre_add1,
                             pre_add2,pre_state,pre_pincode,pre_phno,per_add1,
                             per_add2,per_state,per_pincode,per_phno,mobno,sex,dept)
                             values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

                            String psmd1=eid.getText();
                            String psmd3=name.getText();
                            String psmd2=doj.getText();

                            String psmd4=fname.getText();
                            String psmd5=dob.getText();
                            String psmd6=desg.getText();
                            String psmd7=pre_add1.getText();
                            String psmd8=pre_add2.getText();
                            String psmd9=pre_state.getText();
                            int psmd10=Integer.parseInt(pre_pincode.getText());
                            int psmd11=Integer.parseInt(pre_phno.getText());
                            String psmd12=per_add1.getText();
                            String psmd13=per_add2.getText();
                            String psmd14=per_state.getText();

                            int psmd15=Integer.parseInt(per_pincode.getText());
                            int psmd16=Integer.parseInt(per_phno.getText());
                            int psmd17=Integer.parseInt(mobno.getText());


                            String psmd18=jsex;
                            String psmd19=jdept;




                            psm.setString(1,psmd1);
                            psm.setString(3,psmd3);
                            psm.setString(2,psmd2);

                            psm.setString(4,psmd4);
                            psm.setString(5,psmd5);
                            psm.setString(6,psmd6);
                            psm.setString(7,psmd7);
                            psm.setString(8,psmd8);

                            psm.setString(9,psmd9);
                            psm.setInt(10,psmd10);
                            psm.setInt(11,psmd11);
                            psm.setString(12,psmd12);
                            psm.setString(13,psmd13);
                            psm.setString(14,psmd14);
                            psm.setInt(15,psmd15);
                            psm.setInt(16,psmd16);
                            psm.setInt(17,psmd17);
                            psm.setString(18,psmd18);
                            psm.setString(19,psmd19);

                            int a=psm.executeUpdate();


                            System.out.println(a+" Rows updated.......");

                             eid.setText("");
                             doj.setText("");
                             name.setText("");
                             fname.setText("");
                             dob.setText("");
                             desg.setText("");
                             pre_add1.setText("");
                             pre_add2.setText("");
                             pre_state.setText("");
                             pre_pincode.setText("");
                             pre_phno.setText("");
                             per_add1.setText("");
                             per_add2.setText("");
                             per_state.setText("");
                             per_pincode.setText("");
                             per_phno.setText("");
                             mobno.setText("");


                            status.setText("");


                    }catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e);}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

It does not matter in what order the data is stored.  Database systems store the data in a way they think most efficient.

Generally all tools exposes a way to get the data in ordered way ( say by an `order by` [clause](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/access-help/order-by-clause-HA010341897.aspx))

Answer (score 0):

A common stumbling block for people getting started with parameterized queries against an ACE/Jet (Access) database is that the parameters must be added to the prepared statement in the *exact same order that they appear in the SQL statement*. This is certainly true with ACE/Jet OLEDB so I wouldn't be at all surprised if it was also true for ACE/Jet ODBC (which you are using).

So, change the order in which you issue the `psm.setString` statements to exactly match the order in which the corresponding fields appear in the `INSERT INTO` statement. The ACE/Jet drivers ignore parameter *names*; it's the order in which you add them to the Parameters collection that matters.

Comment: I have changed the order of these statements but not working at all